# Python selenium web-driver javascript execution breaks ability to login, account appears to be shadowbanned

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm writing a python script to scrape some information from a website with selenium. I could log in via the script just fine before adding a JS script (with the goal of scraping rendered HTML). After running the script, I now can't log in at all, regardless of platform/useragent. The webpage appears to refresh after submitting log in info, without returning any errors (i.e. "incorrect username/password"). Any pointers/ideas as to what happened? I'm tempted to think this is a back-end error due to the issue persisting across windows/macos/linux/safari/chrome/edge.

If it matters, the website's robots.txt file contains only "User-Agent: *".
The website was built using zohosites. It is not my own website.

Here is my script so far, the url is the only line excluded.

```
import codecs
import fileinput
import requests
import json
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import time
import sys
import urllib.request
from datetime import date
from htmldate import find_date
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from json import JSONDecoder
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs) 
ua = UserAgent()
UserAgent = ua.random
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={UserAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located([By.NAME, 'name']))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located([By.NAME, 'password']))
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'name')
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')

print(os.getenv("USERNAME"))

username.send_keys(os.getenv("USERNAME"))
password.send_keys(os.getenv("PASSWORD"))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(2)

html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
file = open('rendered_html.html', 'w')
file.write(html)
file.close()
```

Comment: Seems likely that the site banned you for too many / too frequent logins.  We can't answer this here - you will likely need to contact the site and/or look at their terms of service.

Comment: @stdunbar that's what I figured too. Sorry for the noob question, but if I do driver.execute_script() inside of python the script would execute locally right? In other words, I'm not sending that command to the website.

Comment: I usually get this response when I haven't allowed cookies for the appropriate site. If you have, try deleting them all...